# .NET AWS LambdaEntryPoint, UseNLog() not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlog

Used AWS Lambda project with tests template. It has both LocalEntryPoint and LamdaEntryPoint.
Configured NLog for both. LocalEntryPoint works fine, but LambdaEntryPoint doesn't work. I could see the first log entry "LAMBDA TEST - Init WebHost". But some how .UseNLog not working it seems. Log statements in my controller doesn't log as expected incase of LambdaEntryPoint.

```
public class LambdaEntryPoint :

            // The base class must be set to match the AWS service invoking the Lambda function. If not Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer
            // will fail to convert the incoming request correctly into a valid ASP.NET Core request.
            //
            // API Gateway REST API                         -> Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
            // API Gateway HTTP API payload version 1.0     -> Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
            // API Gateway HTTP API payload version 2.0     -> Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyFunction
            // Application Load Balancer                    -> Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.ApplicationLoadBalancerFunction
            // 
            // Note: When using the AWS::Serverless::Function resource with an event type of "HttpApi" then payload version 2.0
            // will be the default and you must make Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyFunction the base class.

            Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The builder has configuration, logging and Amazon API Gateway already configured. The startup class
        /// needs to be configured in this method using the UseStartup<>() method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder"></param>
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                logger.Info("LAMBDA TEST - Init WebHost");
                builder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                        {
                            logging.ClearProviders();
                            logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug);
                        }).UseNLog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex, $"{typeof(LocalEntryPoint).FullName} stopped becuase of exception.");
            }
            finally
            {
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
                LogManager.Flush(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my controller code.

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class InventoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<InventoryController> _logger;

        public InventoryController(ILogger<InventoryController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // GET api/inventory
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("INVENTORY INGESTION Request received. Route: {endpointName}, Method: {method}", "api/inventory", "GET");
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            return new string[] { environment, $"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()}" };
        }
}
```

Need help fixing this.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/issues/148

Answer (score 0):

Try changing into this:

```cs
public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
   protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
   {
       var logger = LogManager.Setup()
          .SetupExtensions(e => e.AutoLoadAssemblies(false))
          .RegisterNLogWeb()
          .LoadConfigurationFromFile("NLog.config", optional: false)
          .LoadConfiguration(builder => builder.LogFactory.AutoShutdown = false)
          .GetCurrentClassLogger();

       logger.Info("LAMBDA TEST - Init WebHost");

       builder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
       {
          logging.ClearProviders();
          logging.AddNLogWeb(new NLogAspNetCoreOptions() {
             ShutdownOnDispose = true,
             RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = true,
          });
       })
       .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

`AutoShutdown = false` and `ShutdownOnDispose = true` tells NLog to let MEL-LoggerFactory trigger flush and shutdown.

Remember also to check the setup in `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.production.json` to see if MEL-Logging-Filtering is discarding output. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Missing-trace%5Cdebug-logs-in-ASP.NET-Core-3%3F

Comment: no luck. My solution doesn't have any appsettings.